# Split integer and non-integer and get mean or median

Tags: r

I got n numbers of random variables through rnorm (n) and also n numbers through:

```
sample (1:100, n, replace = T)
```

and I concatenate these two data so that I have 2n numbers of random variables(=x)

The question is make function(the name of function is mysplit) that split data into integer and non integer and get each mean or median (optional)

I guess i should use function split or tapply but i dont have any idea how to split the data into integer and non integer

Also how can I set the optional function (median) if there is optional part like

```
mysplit(x,n,method = "median")
```

Comment: Once you concatenate, the whole vector becomes `numeric` class

Comment: maybe you mean integer and fractionnal part?

Comment: not fractional part. Just whether the number is integer or not and split them

Answer (score 3):

We can use `split`

```
 lapply(split(v1, grepl("\\.", v1)), mean)
```

If we need a function

```
mysplit <- function(x, n, method = "median"){
   lst <- split(x, grepl("\\.", x))
   lapply(lst, method)
 }

 mysplit(v1, 2, "median")
```

#### data

```
 v1 <- c(1, 2.3, 4.5, 3)
```

Comment: Thank you but how can I make the form of 'mysplit(x,n)'?

Comment: @서명교  Can you update in your post what `x` is?  I have a hard time understanding what that input is.

Comment: You can see the (=x) at 4th line which means the concatenate of two random variables (2n)

Comment: @서명교  So, is it the concatenated vector that goes into the function?.  If that is the case, the `n` is not needed as input

Comment: yes and the function split that vector into integer part and non integer part and get mean or median (optional)

Comment: @서명교  what is `n` doing in the `mysplit` if the input variable is a concatenated?

Comment: I rhink n is needed to get the numbers of vectors

Comment: As you can see in the sample and rnorm

Comment: @서명교  the `split` is based on the integer or numeric element.  So, `n` is not coming into picture there

Comment: Oh then how can i fix the number of vectors?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming your strating data looks like the data d:

```
 d<-data.table(y=as.vector(rbind(rnorm(100),seq(1.0:100.0))))
```

Now, the split function is

```
splitit<-function(d,m)
{
  print(m)
 dd<-data.table(x=d[!(y%%1==0),],n=d[y%%1==0,])
 if(as.numeric(m)==1){ddd<-data.table(mx=mean(dd$x),mn=mean(dd$n))}
 if(as.numeric(m)==0){ddd<-data.table(mx=median(dd$x),mn=median(dd$n))}
 return(ddd)
}

c<-splitit(d,1)
```

Output :

```
> c
    mx   mn
1: 0.05145718 50.5
> c<-splitit(d,1)
[1] 1
> c
        mx   mn
   1: -0.05396085 50.5
```

This should help!

Comment: When floating points are involved it is safer to use `all.equal()` than an equality comparison with `==`.